# Is the fact that complex roots of polynomials with real coefficients occur in pairs of any use if we have a polynomial and know one real root only?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, proof-explanation, roots

Consider the following theorem appearing in *Linear Algebra Done Right*

> 4.15 Polynomials with real coefficients have zeros in pairs.
>
> Suppose $p\in P(\mathbb{C})$ is a polynomial with real coefficients.
> If $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ is a zero of $p$, then so is
> $\bar{\lambda})$.

The proof is quite simple. If we have a polynomial $p\in P(\mathbb{C})$ then it has form

$$\sum_{i=0}^m a_i z^i$$

with the $a_i\in\mathbb{R}$.

Suppose $\lambda$ is a root of $p$.

$$\sum_{i=0}^m a_i \lambda^i=0$$

And taking the complex conjugate of both sides

$$\sum_{i=0}^m a_i \bar{\lambda}^i=0$$

so $\bar{\lambda}$ is a root.

My question is about when $\lambda$ is a real number.

It seems that the only value of the theorem in that case is, for example, if we have a third degree polynomial and we find one complex root, then we know that the complex conjugate is the third root.

If we have a polynomial of degree $m$ and one real root, does the theorem give us any useful information?

It does not seem to tell us anything about the multiplicity of real roots, for example, correct?

Comment: You are correct. That theorem tells you precisely what it says and no more. The complex roots occur in pairs. About all you can say about the real roots with that information is that there are an even or odd number  of real roots depending on whether the degree is even or odd. And to say that you must count the real roots with their multiplicities.